# fetching value between an anchor tag with bs4 or regex

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

is there a way to get the value between the anchor tags? so in this case 'Bjelica, Nemanja' using beautiful soup?

```
 <a href="/wiki/Nemanja_Bjelica" title="Nemanja Bjelica">Bjelica, Nemanja</a>
```

I tried to do it like this

```
name = k.find('a')['title']
```

but i want to get the name between the anchor tags. Any hints?

Comment: IIRC use the `text` variable attached to it, eg: `soup.find('a').text`

Comment: no way... i literally spent hours trying to format the titles i got. Thank mate, much love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the text content of a tag. As one of commenter mentioned, you can use `.text`, but I personally prefer `.get_text()` [which actually gets called to generate `.text` anyway] because it lets you add separators for keeping texts from multiple inline elements getting smushed together. You can check out the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) for more examples and options.